# Setting leading in LaTeX using \fontsize: what are the advantages and disadvantages?

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment

LaTeX has several ways of setting leading without changing anything else, including:

- `\fontsize{default font size}{value of leading}\selectfont`
- `\linespread{ratio of leading to original}`
- `\leading{value of leading}` % requires the leading package

Some go in the preamble, and some go in the body of the text.

I would like to use the first way above (`\fontsize`) exclusively, because I can set font size as well. Does this have any advantages or disadvantages compared to the other ways?

Comment: Why not opt for or use [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use the first way, unless indirectly, by redefining the meaning of all font size changing commands: `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\Large`, ..., `\small`, `\footnotesize`, ...

The reason is that any command that internally uses `\normalsize` (or another command of the series above) would spoil your hand crafted leading. What are these commands? To begin with, there is `\begin{document}`; also `\caption`, `\begin{figure}`, `\begin{table}`, `\marginpar` call `\normalsize`; not to forget that it is issued during the output routine, for setting headers and footers.

Where do the definitions you need to change reside? In `.clo` files; for the `book` class they are in `bk10.clo`, `bk11.clo` and `bk12.clo`, corresponding to the initial option given to `\documentclass`. For other classes there are different files (you can see which one is loaded by examining the log file).

The method with `\linespread` and `\leading` are equivalent, the second is perhaps easier to understand.

Using explicit `\fontsize` commands in the document is not recommendable, in my opinion.